# linux on old notebook Compal FL90 stops working when no keyboard or mouse input

Tags: drivers, hardware

I am trying to run Ubuntu linux on an old notebook. The computer stops doing anything after some moments when no keyboard input or mouse movement was done. I went through the installation process by constantly moving the mouse to keep installation task done. Every task seems to stop working and no CPU usage occurs. If I press a key or move mouse the system continues work without problems but stops again after some moments.
I tried doing "watch -n 3 free -m" and that freezes as well as cronjobs.

The system has 4GB Ram installed. The CPU is a IntelCore2 Duo T8300 @ 2.4 GHz. Win 10 used to run at an ok level of perfomance.

The system works flawlessly while using it for anything and keeping constant mouse-usage or keyboard inputs. When no inputs are done the CPU stops working, no processes are running and the LED of CPU is not blinking. The display is kept in the last state with display running and what you where just doing. Any current process like a running command or an incoming SSH connection are on hold. E.g. when installing the system or using apt for download I have to keep the mouse moving while it downloads otherwise it does not proceed.
When using the touchpad or mouse or press a key the CPU starts working and everything continues and runs normal for some seconds.
I also tried a Debian distribution and it has the exact same problems. I am using the latest long-time-support Ubuntu.

I found out it has to do with softlocking the CPU but I do not know what it is exactly or how to solve and I cannot find the logfile I read that in.

Maybe someone know what this error on the screenshot means as I am sure it has to do with it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T41NZjaru4mml2hzvpG4IISx-yxt7LIu/view?usp=sharing

Any idea how I can fix that or how to get closer to the problem?

I am not sure which information I must provide to get help. Please let me know and help me learn =)

Comment: When you say "stops doing anything", do you mean the computer goes to sleep? Which version of Ubuntu are you running on the machine? How much RAM is installed? Could you [edit] your question to show this information?

Comment: no, Ubuntu will not go on this old computer. Choose a more lightweight Ubuntu flavour: Ubuntu Mate, xubuntu, lubuntu.

Comment: I edited the information. The system itself is capable of running Ubuntu technically. It is even normal usable when working on it. The main problem is when working on it via SSH it is useless as you have to constantly hit a key or touchpad on the notebook to have the SSH connection work.

Comment: google "rcu_sched detected stalls on cpus/tasks" but it doesn't look hopeful

Comment: My solution was: install FreeBSD. Though nowadays I even have this problem in the Win11 Linux Subsystem. FYI Clonezilla in safeMode runs fine so maybe the grub options from that do work here as well